# Syntax Error when using Wordpress do_shortcode in between an HTML string

Tags: php, wordpress, string, woocommerce, shortcode

I'm having a syntax error of *"unexpected T_ECHO on line 7"* and I checked  [PHP parse/syntax errors; and how to solve them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them/18092318#18092318) thread trying to understand and solve that issue.

But I can't seem to find a way to solve this with my limited PHP knowledge.
Below is the code snippet I want to have on my Woocommerce/Wordpress website.
I am using an altered version of [Display a custom div block for woocommerce out of stock product variations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53971339/display-a-custom-div-block-for-woocommerce-out-of-stock-product-variations/53971575#53971575) answer code which works flawlessly.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_variation', 'custom_outofstock_variation_addition', 10, 3 );
function custom_outofstock_variation_addition( $data, $product, $variation ) {
    if( $variation->is_on_backorder() ){
        $data['availability_html'] .= '<table class="variations mto-cont" cellspacing="0">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="made-to-order"><a> 'echo do_shortcode('[nm_lightbox title="Made to Order " content_image_id="5110"]');'</a></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>';
    }
    return $data;
}
```

So what I wish to reach is to have Wordpress to do a shortcode in between `<td class="made-to-order"><a>` and `</a></td>`.

How should this code be rewritten in order to make this work?

Comment: You can not use `echo`, when you are already in a string concatentation context. Instead, you need to continue to use string concatenation here. `'…<a> '.do_shortcode(…).'</a>…'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to **concatenate** `do_shortcode()` function in your string of HTML instead of using `echo` inside it like *(as you are returning that string at the end)*:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_variation', 'custom_outofstock_variation_addition', 10, 3 );
function custom_outofstock_variation_addition( $data, $product, $variation ) {
    if( $variation->is_on_backorder() ){
        $data['availability_html'] .= '<table class="variations mto-cont" cellspacing="0">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="made-to-order"><a> ' . do_shortcode('[nm_lightbox title="Made to Order …" content_image_id="5110"]') . '</a></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>';
    }
    return $data;
}
```